# Call member function on each element in a container

Tags: c++, stl, boost, coding-style

This question is a matter of style, since you can always write a for loop or something similar; however, is there a less obtrusive STL or BOOST equivalent to writing:

```
for (container<type>::iterator iter = cointainer.begin();
     iter != cointainer.end();
     iter++)
 iter->func();
```

?

Something like (imagined) this:

```
call_for_each(container.begin(), container.end(), &Type::func);
```

I think it would be 1) less typing, 2) easier to read, 3) less changes if you decided to change base type/container type.

EDIT:
Thanks for your help, now, what if I wanted to pass some arguments to the member function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found out that boost bind seems to be well suited for the task, plus you can pass additional arguments to the method:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

struct Foo {
    Foo(int value) : value_(value) {
    }

    void func(int value) {
        std::cout << "member = " << value_ << " argument = " << value << std::endl;
    }

private:
    int value_;
};

int main() {
    std::vector<Foo> foo_vector;

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        foo_vector.push_back(Foo(i));

    std::for_each(foo_vector.begin(), foo_vector.end(),
        boost::bind(&Foo::func, _1, 1));
}
```

Comment: +1 because you beat me by 5minutes with that bind answer :p (oh, std::mem_fun_ref is crap when using with bound arguments!)

Comment: +1, for figuring this out without all by yourself and for using Boost. Cheers!

Comment: what i mean is when you have reference-to-references when you have the member function has a reference parameter. boost::bind solves it so nicely :)

Answer (score 25):

```
 #include <algorithm>  // for_each
 #include <functional> // bind

 // ...

 std::for_each(container.begin(), container.end(), 
                   std::bind(&Type::func));
```

See [`std::for_each`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/for_each) and [`std::bind`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind) documentation for details.

Missed your edit: Anyway here is another way of achieving what you want without using Boost, if ever need be:

```
std::for_each(foo_vector.begin(), foo_vector.end(),
    std::bind(&Foo::func, std::placeholders::_1));
```

Comment: +1. or alternatively mem_fun_ref if the container contains the objects instead of pointers to them

Comment: @litb: Thanks, I hesitated about both BOOST_FOREACH and mem_fun_ref(). I can never decide when I am writing too much or too little :P

Answer (score 5):

You can use [std::for_each](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/for_each.html) or [boost's foreach constructs](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/doc/html/foreach.html).

Use boost's BOOST_FOREACH or BOOST_REVERSE_FOREACH when you don't want to move the logic into another function.

Comment: +1. BOOST_FOREACH(type &t, container) t.func(); does look quite neat

Answer (score 2):

Since C++11 standard the BOOST approach is standardized with different syntax as the "range-based-loop":

```
class Foo {
    Foo(int x);
    void foo();
}
vector<int> list = {Foo(1),Foo(2),Foo(3)};
for(auto &item: list) item.foo();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you actually want to improve performance rather than just pretty up your code, what you really need is a map function.  Eric Sink wrote a [.net implementation](http://www.ericsink.com/entries/multicore_map.html)

Comment: Thanks, I'm looking for a generic C++ (platform independent) solution.