# Making combinations with the elements of std::vector

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, combinations, stdvector

In the following code, the aim is to call `foo` in combination to each element of `vector<Grid> gr`. Is there a built-in STL function or if not, what is the best way to do this for large-size containers? Note that, since `grid[0]` affects `grid[1]` as well, `grid[1]` should not call the function on `grid[0]`. So, no permutations but only combinations. BTW, [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/719043/call-member-function-on-each-element-in-a-container) does not answer my question.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

struct Grid
{
    void foo (Grid& g) {}
};

int main()
{
    vector<Grid> gr(3);
    gr[0].foo (gr[1]);
    gr[0].foo (gr[2]);
    gr[1].foo (gr[2]);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Call member function on each element in a container](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/719043/call-member-function-on-each-element-in-a-container)

Comment: Probably you could do some sort of a sorcery with [`std::next_permutation`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/next_permutation/)

Comment: It's two nested iterations, either with a `for` loop or with `std::for_each`.

Comment: Oh! Oh! I've done this!  Now I just have to find it!

Answer (score 6):

This is not too hard to do with a nested loop since you are using only combinations of two.  That being said, my favorite library is a combinations library documented here:

http://howardhinnant.github.io/combinations.html

which contains complete (and free) source code.  below I show both ways:

1. Using the combinations library.
2. Writing your own nested loops.

---

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include "../combinations/combinations"

struct Grid
{
    int id_;

    Grid (int id) : id_(id) {}
    void foo (Grid& g)
    {
        std::cout << "Doing " << id_ << " and " << g.id_ << '\n';
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<Grid> gr{0, 1, 2, 3};
    for_each_combination(gr.begin(), gr.begin()+2, gr.end(),
        [](std::vector<Grid>::iterator first, std::vector<Grid>::iterator last)
        {
            first->foo(*std::prev(last));
            return false;
        }
    );
    std::cout << '\n';
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < gr.size()-1; ++i)
        for (unsigned j = i+1; j < gr.size(); ++j)
            gr[i].foo(gr[j]);
}
```

This outputs:

```
Doing 0 and 1
Doing 0 and 2
Doing 0 and 3
Doing 1 and 2
Doing 1 and 3
Doing 2 and 3

Doing 0 and 1
Doing 0 and 2
Doing 0 and 3
Doing 1 and 2
Doing 1 and 3
Doing 2 and 3
```

The solution without the combination library is actually simpler for this case (combination of N things taken 2 at a time).  However, as the number of items taken at a time rises, or if that is run time information, then the combination library really starts to earn its keep.

Answer (score 1):

It certainly looks like you could use a nested loop here, one for each of the 2 integers you have in each call to foo()